# Weird stacking of some text labels over others?

Tags: bug, review, design

I'm browsing questions normally.

I access review queues, everything seems normal:

[image: Screenshot of the FP-queue on Super User, with Tabs Outliner on the left hand of the screen.]

Well not quite, if I scroll to get more info:

[image: Screenshot of the FP-queue on Super User, with Tabs Outliner on the left hand of the screen where the content is scrolled to the right, which makes the left nav collide with the content of the review screen.]

---

> <sub>I'm not able to reproduce this in the First Posts queue on SO or the close queue on SU... can you give us some more information on your setup? Do you have any userscripts or addons that may be causing this? – Catija♦</sub>

<sub>This is Chromium 47 with no userscripts am aware of, no other plugins than Tabs Outliner. Tried to reproduce using Opera but couldn't.</sub>

---

After several reviews done with the glitch on, I've mastered how to have it not to cause me issues when reviewing. Just let the labels float around while acting and have them far from any control or text area you have to click.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in the First Posts queue on SO or the close queue on SU... can you give us some more information on your setup? Do you have any userscripts or addons that may be causing this?

Comment: There is a very big add-on on the left of the screen....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Head to [Edit profile and settings](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/YOUR_USER_ID_HERE).
2. Find "Navigation" in "Preferences".
3. Find "Hide left navigation (When you check this box, the left navigation will no longer be pinned to the left of the page on Q&A sites.)" in "Navigation".
4. Hit it!
6. Profit! If anything failed, go back to step 5 and try again.